# How to find maxima and minima of a function involving a factorial

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

i need to find the value of y when the bell curve for the following function reaches its maximum , i can solve the problem easily on a MAS software but i needed to know a more mathematical approach . here's the simplified equation

$$\frac{3^{-y}}{(25-y)! y!}$$

and here's the original equation which i need to solve

$$\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{25} 25!}{3^y (25-y)! y!}$$

in a nutshell i need to find the value of y when the above function reaches its maxima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

If $T_y=\frac{\left(\frac34\right)^{25}25!}{3^y(25-y)! y!}$

Clearly, $0\le y\le 25$

$$\frac{T_{y+1}}{T_y}=\frac{3^y(25-y)!y!}{3^{y+1}(25-y-1)!(y+1)!}=\frac{25-y}{3(y+1)}$$

Check when $\frac{T_{y+1}}{T_y}>\text{ or } = \text{ or } <1$

Comment: The pattern is like : http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/binomial-theorem-for-a-positive-integral-index/greatest-binomial-coefficient.aspx

Comment: Intuitively, why does comparing it to 1 help get you the answer? Does it have to do with the Ratio test to see if a series absolutely converges?

Comment: @dmonopoly, as each term is positive and  $a>b>0\iff \frac ab>1$